# How to avoid delays caused by garbage collection?

Tags: memory-leaks, garbage-collection, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Using MicroPython on a Raspberry Pi Pico I receive a pulse wave (~17ms on, ~3ms off) then output relating to that. When garbage collector kicks in it messes up my output for about 6ms (too long for what I'm doing). I disabled garbage collection (`gc.disable()`) which works for about 1 second before it runs out of memory and crashes. I'm not creating variables frequently. One section that seems to be using up memory:

```
from gc import mem_alloc
from time import ticks_us, ticks_diff

class Example_class:

    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
        self.b = 1

example_object = Example_class(1)

start_time = ticks_us()

while True:
    example_object.a=0.000001 * ticks_diff(ticks_us(),start_time)
    m0 = mem_alloc() #used for demonstration
    example_object.b=example_object.a*1
    m1 = mem_alloc() #used for demonstration
    print(m1-m0) #used for demonstration
    print(mem_alloc()) #used for demonstration
```

Here I create a Class, initialize an object, then run a loop on that object. I should be creating no new memory, all I do is take `example_object.a`, multiply it by 0.1 and overwrite previous `example_object.b`'s value. `print(m1-m0)` always returns 16 and `print(mem_alloc())` returns an increasing counter. If I run `gc.disable()` at the top and remove all memory functions it crashes in seconds. Where is the memory leak?

This also happens for `random.randint(0,1)` or alike, ticks_diff happens to be what I use in my code. If I change multiplication from 0.000001 to 1 the issue goes away. Somehow this relates to floating point calculation.

Why this code keeps taking up memory? How can I stop that? I want to run with garbage collection turned off, or any other way to avoid the 6ms delays.

Comment: Should `ticks_diff(ticks_us,start_time)` be `ticks_diff(ticks_us(),start_time)` ?

Comment: My first answer was yes, but when I went to check my code, it does in fact run identically with or without the (), so perhaps I'm missing something. But regardless I have edited the post to add "ticks_us()"

Comment: on running this code (`version 3.11`) i get: `cannot import name 'mem_alloc' from 'gc'`.

Comment: @D.L I think this may be an issue with "micropython" vs regular python-(https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/gc.html)- I have had lots of issues with the libraries being slightly different in the past. For reference, when I run the code on my machine I get as output:
32
5344
16
5376
16
5408
16
5440
16
5472
16
5504
16
5536
16
5568
16
5600
16
5632
16
5664
16
5696
16
5728
16
5760
16
5792
16
5824
16
5856
16
5888
16
5920
16
5952
16
5984
16
6016
etc etc

Comment: @Jack,  yes,  this seems to be the case since `ticks_us` and `ticks_diff` also do not exist in the `time` module (in regular python).

Comment: I would like to take a look at this later today when I'm back home with my micropython devices, but in general if you've got something like this that is really timing sensitive I would consider implementing in C instead where you don't have to worry about the garbage collector at all. You may also want to ask in the [Micropython discussions on GitHub](https://github.com/orgs/micropython/discussions).